# Вывод JSON - node.js + sqllite3

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get("/api/itemhome", function(req, res){
db.get("SELECT * FROM itemhome", [], function(err, itemhome){

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

          var json = JSON.stringify({ 
            itemhome: itemhome, 
          });

          res.end(json);

});
```

> Возвращает первую запись - id 1

Как вернуть **все**?

Comment: Если почитать документацию по sqlite3, то можно увидеть, что про метод `get()` там написано буквально следующее: `Runs the SQL query with the specified parameters and calls the callback with the first result row afterwards.` Очевидно, Вам следует использовать не `get()`, а `all()`.

Comment: @Yaant, думаю стоит преобразовать ваш комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если почитать [документацию по sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API), то можно увидеть, что про метод `get()` там написано буквально следующее:

> Runs the SQL query with the specified parameters and calls the
>   callback with the first result row afterwards.

Очевидно, Вам следует использовать не `get()`, а `all()`